# Scapy: How to change the IP address of an ICMP Error message

Tags: scapy

As you all probably know, an ICMP error message encapsulates the original IP packet inside it, so that the ICMP packet is actually IP()/ICMP()/IP()

How do I change the original IP fields?

p.src = "10.0.0.1" changes the current IP()/ICMP() packet and not the original one.

Many thanks,
N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer.
Apparently, there's a layer called IPerror which is used in these cases.

N